# How can I create a single shorcut to open a set of programs?

Tags: scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity

Currently, I have a set of shorcuts to open several applications. I use `xbindkeys` to do so. I have something like this:

- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> -> sublime
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> -> pcmanfm
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> -> skype
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> -> terminal

Now, I'd like to use a single shortcut to open all of them. How can I do that?

BR,
Sebastian

Comment: super+a -> "sublime & pcmanfm & skype & xterm &" in ~/.xbindkeysrc

Comment: Is it possible to add a delay a couple of seconds before launching a program? I need to start pcmanfm first, then wait for a couple of seconds before launching sublime.

Comment: command; sleep 5; foo & bar; baz - You need to understand what ; and & and && do though. There is probably a better way.

Comment: @Thomas that's the way to go, post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Put everything into a shell script and start the shell script with your shortcut.